# Consuming both Strict and Streamed WebSocket Messages in Akka

Tags: websocket, akka, akka-stream, akka-http

I am experimenting with building a web socket service using Akka HTTP.  I need to handle Strict messages that arrive in totality, as well as handle Streamed messages that arrive in m multiple frames.  I am using a route with handleWebSocketMessages() to pass the handling of web sockets off to a flow.  The code I have looks something like this:

```
val route: Route =
  get {
    handleWebSocketMessages(createFlow())
  }

def createFlow(): Flow[Message, Message, Any] = Flow[Message]
  .collect {
    case TextMessage.Strict(msg) ⇒ msg
    case TextMessage.Streamed(stream) => ??? // <= What to do here??
  }
  .via(createActorFlow())
  .map {
    case msg: String ⇒ TextMessage.Strict(msg)
  }

def createActorFlow(): Flow[String, String, Any] = {
  // Set Up Actors
  // ... (this is working)
  Flow.fromSinkAndSource(in, out)
}
```

I am not really sure how two handle both Strict and Streamed messages.  I realize I could do something like this :

```
  .collect {
    case TextMessage.Strict(msg) ⇒ Future.successful(msg)
    case TextMessage.Streamed(stream) => stream.runFold("")(_ + _)
  }
```

But now my stream has to handle Future[String] rather than just Strings, which I am then not sure how to handle, especially since obviously I need to handle messages in order.

I did see this akka issue, which seems to be somewhat related, but not exactly what I need (I don't think?).

https://github.com/akka/akka/issues/20096

Any help would be appriciated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The ultimate answer based on the below (thanks to svezfaz) answer turned out to be something like this:

```
val route: Route =
  get {
    handleWebSocketMessages(createFlow())
  }

def createFlow(): Flow[Message, Message, Any] = Flow[Message]
  .collect {
    case TextMessage.Strict(msg) ⇒ 
      Future.successful(MyCaseClass(msg))
    case TextMessage.Streamed(stream) => stream
      .limit(100)                   // Max frames we are willing to wait for
      .completionTimeout(5 seconds) // Max time until last frame
      .runFold("")(_ + _)           // Merges the frames
      .flatMap(msg => Future.successful(MyCaseClass(msg)))
  }
  .mapAsync(parallelism = 3)(identity)
  .via(createActorFlow())
  .map {
    case msg: String ⇒ TextMessage.Strict(msg)
  }

def createActorFlow(): Flow[MyCaseClass, String, Any] = {
  // Set Up Actors as source and sink (not shown)
  Flow.fromSinkAndSource(in, out)
}
```

Comment: What about this: case msg @ TextMessage.Streamed(t) =>
        msg.toStrict(5.seconds).flatMap(...) ?

Answer (score 4):

Folding sounds like a sensible option. Handling future in your streams can be done using (e.g.)

```
flowOfFutures.mapAsync(parallelism = 3)(identity)
```

Please note that mapAsync does preserve the order of the incoming messages, as per [docs](http://doc.akka.io/api/akka/2.4.3/index.html#akka.stream.scaladsl.Flow@mapAsync[T](parallelism:Int)(f:Out=%3Escala.concurrent.Future[T]):FlowOps.this.Repr[T]).

On a different note, other sensible precautions to handle streamed WS messages could be to use completionTimeout and limit to bound time and space for the message to fold (e.g.)

```
stream.limit(x).completionTimeout(5 seconds).runFold(...)
```

Comment: Thanks svezfaz.  Your tips helped unlock my issue.  I have it working now.

Comment: Adding more convenience methods for this case is on our radar by the way, keep an eye on: https://github.com/akka/akka/issues/20096

Comment: Thanks.  I subscribed to the issue.  I am hoping that this question / answer will help people out in the mean time.