# Play 2.6 WebSocket proxy using Akka - How to handle Streamed Text vs Strict Text

Tags: playframework, akka, akka-stream, akka-http

While writing a WebSocket proxy in Play 2.6 (based on [Websocket Proxy using Play 2.6 and akka streams](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43365446/websocket-proxy-using-play-2-6-and-akka-streams/45859968)), I am facing a problem handling streamed text.

Concerned code:

```
def proxySocket: WebSocket = WebSocket.accept[String, String] { _ =>
  Flow[String].map(s => TextMessage(s))
  .via(websocketFlow)
  .map(_.asTextMessage.getStrictText)
}
```

This is working for proxying to a local websocket server. But while proxying to a remote server, it leads to the following error:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot get strict text for streamed message.

We can get stream message via `_.asTextMessage.getStreamedText`, but I am not able to figure out how to convert it into `String`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the [documentation](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-http/10.0.9/scala/http/websocket-support.html#model) for Akka HTTP (the underlying engine in Play) states, one cannot expect the message to always be `Strict`:

> When receiving data from the network connection the WebSocket implementation tries to create a `Strict` message whenever possible, i.e. when the complete data was received in one chunk. However, the actual chunking of messages over a network connection and through the various streaming abstraction layers is not deterministic from the perspective of the application. Therefore, application code must be able to handle both streamed and strict messages and not expect certain messages to be strict. **(Particularly, note that tests against `localhost` will behave differently than tests against remote peers where data is received over a physical network connection.)**

To handle both `Strict` and `Streamed` messages, you could do something like the following (which is inspired by this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36535143/consuming-both-strict-and-streamed-websocket-messages-in-akka/36537894#36537894)):

```scala
def proxySocket: WebSocket = WebSocket.accept[String, String] { _ =>
  Flow[String]
    .map(TextMessage(_))
    .via(websocketFlow)
    .collect {
      case TextMessage.Strict(text) =>
        Future.successful(text)
      case TextMessage.Streamed(textStream) =>
        textStream
          .limit(100)
          .completionTimeout(10 seconds)
          .runFold("")(_ + _)
          .flatMap(x => Future.successful(x))
    }
    .mapAsync(parallelism = 3)(identity)
}
```